# '&&' not working in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

In the link https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-udf.html, it is clearly mentioned that `A && B` is same as `A AND B`. But when i tried to use `&&` in one of my hive query, it was not working (I am using hive-0.9.0-cdh4.1.2).

Sample Input:

12  23

2   6

Table schema as `test(a int, b int)`. When I performed `SELECT CASE WHEN (a<10 && b<10) THEN a+b END FROM test;`, I got an exception message saying "FAILED: ParseException line 1:24 cannot recognize input near '&' 'b' '<' in expression specification".

Expected Output :

`NULL`
`8`

But when I replaced `&&` with `AND`, it gave correct result. I want to know why this happened. Any help much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had run into this issue sometime ago and tried to do some research which remained incomplete because of other things. But what I found was that this is some parsing related issue. To be precise, ANTLR is not able to provide suitable parser to parse this query.

You could probably try using the latest version of Hive which has an upgraded version of ANTLR. But i'm still not sure that it will work even with that. To be frank, I wonder if **&&** and **||** have ever worked.